# How to generate id and name attribute input form and model dynamically using Entity-Attribute-Value EAV?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I need to use Entity-Attribute-Value (EAV) approach for my database design. These are my models.

```
public class TableMetadataTemplate
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string? TableName { get; set; }
    public string? FieldName { get; set; }
    public string? FieldType { get; set; }
    public string? FieldLabel { get; set; }
    public int Sequence { get; set; }
    public bool Required { get; set; }
    public string? DefalutValue { get; set; }
}

public class TableMetadata
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Guid TableMetadataTemplateId { get; set; }
    public Guid RecordId { get; set; }
    public string? FieldValue { get; set; }
}
```

This is the sample data in the table:

[image]

I am using Razor pages and this is my code for the Create form:

```
@foreach (var row in Model.TableMetadataTemplate)
{
    var fieldType = row.FieldType;
    switch (fieldType)
    {
        case "TEXT":
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="@fieldName" class="control-label">@fieldLabel</label>
                <input type="text" asp-for="@row.FieldName" class="form-control" value="">
                <span asp-validation-for="@fieldName" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            break;
        
    }
}
```

[image]

Note: The above is just one example.

But, as I inspect the textbox attributes, it doesn't generate the correct id and name attribute value that I need.

```
<input type="text" id="row_FieldName" name="row.FieldName" value="">
```

The correct id and name attribute value that I need is something like below:

```
<input type="text" id="TableMetadataTemplate_application_name" name="TableMetadataTemplate.application_name" value="">
```

Comment: Hi @Steve, for your shared correct id and name, what is the ApplicationName? The actual value of the `FieldName` property? If so, why you want to do like this? It will cause model binding error if you also want to post the input value to backend. The correct way is to use `PropertyName.PropertyName`, the first propertyName depends on what you set in the PageModel, you use `Model.TableMetadataTemplate`, so the propertyName is the same as the ModelName, so current correct name should be `ModelName.PropertyName`.

Comment: If you want to receive the list model, the correct name should be `ModelName[index].PropertyName`. So it is better for you to pls share your scenario with us.

Comment: @Rena, I have added the sample table data in the original post. In the [TableMetadataTemplates] table, there is a record which the fieldname is "application_name". Not sure how can I create a dynamic table which can have dynamic property so that I use it at `asp-for` and to bind it during form posting.

Comment: @Steve EAV is a well known *bad database design*. Despite the name, you no longer have entities with attributes at all, just names and values with no type, constraints or validity. As for the code, it behaves as expected - it generates an input and labels for the field named `FieldName` in the object `row. `asp-for` is used to specify which property to bind to. It's meant to work with concrete types and attributes, eg `Customer` and `Name`, `Address` etc

Comment: At the database level, the only reason to want to use an EAV schema is to store arbitrary attributes. Known attributes are stored in their own columns, allowing easy querying, indexing, inserting etc. Even for arbitrary attributes you can use XML columns in almost all databases for nearly 20 years, and JSON for a decade or more. In SQL Server, you can have ~30K sparse columns per table (columns that are usually empty), backed by an XML field. Databases offer querying and even indexing XML and JSON values

Answer (score 1):

From your description, it seems you want to bind the value to backend. but the `ApplicationName` here is the actual value of your property `FieldName`.

You need know that model binding binds the property by name attribute. That is to say the value of the name attribute should match the property name.

### Example for further explanation

`Model.TableMetadataTemplate` is a List model type. If you want to post the value to this type property, you need set the unique name like:`ModelName[index].propertyname` no matter your foreach loop contains one or multiple records.

Page:

```
@page
@model IndexModel
<form method="post">
    @for (int i=0;i< Model.TableMetadataTemplate.Count();i++)
    {

        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" asp-for="@Model.TableMetadataTemplate[i].FieldName" class="form-control" value="">
        </div>            
    }
    <input type="submit" value="Post"/>
</form>
```

Backend:

```
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{      
    //you can see the value here when form submit...
    [BindProperty]    
    public List<TableMetadataTemplate> TableMetadataTemplate { get; set; }    

    public async Task OnGet()
    {
        // be sure set the data value here, otherwise `Model.TableMetadataTemplate` in page will get null exception...
        TableMetadataTemplate =xxx 
    }
    public void OnPost()
    {
         //do your stuff...
    }        
}
```

Comment: Your code looks the same as mine. Just that my object name is `row`

Comment: Pls check my previous comment and share more details. My current code is used to generated the id/name with value `TableMetadataTemplate_FieldName`/`TableMetadataTemplate.FieldName`.

Comment: Ok, I have updated the original post with more info

Comment: Hi @Steve, I have updated my answer and explain how does the model binding work. Pls check if I understand your scenario or not.

Comment: I tried your code but when I inspect the html, it is `<input type="text" class="form-control" value="" id="TableMetadataTemplate_0__FieldName" name="TableMetadataTemplate[0].FieldName">`

Comment: Hi @Steve, yep. Why you insist on `name=TableMetadataTemplate.Application`? This is not the correct model binding name...